# what to do with page fault from copy_from_user()?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have the following system call:

```
long do_print(int n, char *p){
  char tmp[n]; //allocate array of n bytes
  int ret = copy_from_user(tmp,p,n); 
  if (!ret){
    //do something with tmp
  }
  return ret; 
}
```

which return non-zero value for `n>5000` (I reckon because of page fault).

How do I force the copy to be successful. In other words, what do I do if the system call return non-zero value?

Answer (score 4):

Allocating a big array on the stack is not something you should, or really can do. The linux kernel operates with a small stack, usually 2 memory pages. Equally more dangerous is this if your `char tmp[n];` relies on an `n` that comes from user space, letting user space potentially crash the kernel. In a situation such as this, you'll have to dynamically allocate memory instead of using a buffer on the stack.

As to what you'll do if copy_from_user() fails, the user has lied to the kernel, and passed something wrong down to the kernel.

The normal way to handle that is to bail out of whatever you're performing, and pass -EFAULT back up to user space.

Comment: in the user-space code, I made sure to allocate n bytes to the pointers. What do I do with -EINVAL value?

Comment: @user1734905 You handle it like you handle any other error. Also, nos was referring to `n` as in size of the array you use on the kernel stack. You definitely don't want userspace to be able to crash the kernel.

Comment: @user1734905 Then perhaps something's gone wrong at a different place. Have you verified that that the `n` is the same value in the kernel as in the user space code ? I don't know what you're implementing (e.g. a system call, a read() function in a character device, etc.), but you can look at other examples, e.g. [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/ioctl.c#L25) , which implements an ioctl() call - in that example if copy_from_user() fails, it'll cause ioctl() in user space to return -1,(and errno to be EFAULT). Still, you need to fix the code to not allocate on the stack.